# How to delete O365 Team Sites

Tags: office-365, site, delete, team-sites

Firstly, I apologize if I'm not using correct terminology. I am pretty new to SP. In our case, we're using SP Online.

After logging into O365 and clicking on the "SharePoint" main icon, it takes us to

```
https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx
```

This is the page showing the Modern Team Sites which use Office 365 Groups.

At this page, a developer created a new site with the "Create Site" option. Now he would like it deleted, but he/I can't work out how to do this. I did a lot of googling, and found this page which describes the process...

[Delete a site, team site, or subsite in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-a-site-team-site-or-subsite-in-Office-365-bc37b743-0cef-475e-9a8c-8fc4d40179fb)

Due to UI changes or some other reason, the steps to get to Site Settings are a bit different than described, but I did manage to find it under:

```
https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/RobTest/_layouts/15/settings.aspx
```

The thing is that the "Delete this site" option does not appear anywhere here.

I can confirm that:
- the login being used is an "Owner" of the Office 365 Group that is created automatically when the site was created.
- Going to `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/RobTest/_layouts/15/user.aspx` , I have added this login to the "Rob Test Owners" group, and this group has "Full Control".

Obviously I must be doing something wrong ... could someone please tell me how I can get the "Delete this Site" link (or some other way to delete the site) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The link is hidden, and you'd have to type (copy paste it) to reach the delete site option.

Navigate to `_layouts/15/deleteweb.aspx` in the site you want to delete (as owner). In your case it would be

```
https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/RobTest/_layouts/15/deleteweb.aspx
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Cheers. Is there by any chance also a "hidden" page to allow one to access the "Title, description, and logo" settings

Comment: @NevV I guess so. If you have an on Premise solution or a real site collection online, you can find the URL's there. Navigate to https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/settings.aspx, and you can find the things you want there. :)

Comment: thanks for you help, unfortunately that link takes me to the settings for the "main" SharePoint site. As for the O365 Team Sites the settings page is https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>/_layouts/15/settings.aspx but no options to change Logo etc. appear there.

Comment: @NevV How about this link? _layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the question was answered but I want to offer another solution (may be newly exposed feature O365 Sharepoint).  I too wanted to do the same thing but couldn't find option in normal place (no Site Settings).

HOWEVER, it looks like you can now do so as follows:
-go to the group's site
-go to Settings menu (cog) and choose Site Information
-Delete site option is here

I did this AFTER deleting the actual group through O365 admin so not sure if it would otherwise delete the group but you may have to go delete the group specifically in O365 Admin - Group section.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a O365 Group Team Site or O365 Team Group Site:
Click the waffle, People, then click the associated group under Groups.
Click the ellipsis at top right and edit the group; at the bottom of the edit panel you will see Delete Group.
It takes a while for it to actually be deleted...